# How Security in MongoDB works (using x.509 cert)

Tags: mongodb, authentication, security, ssl, x509

I Read through many documents in the mongoDB doc, still unclear how authentication works for clients an member of replica set(using x.509).

Found a resource "http://pe-kay.blogspot.in/2016/02/securing-mongodb-using-x509-certificate.html"
which was well documented, still not clear as how authentication happens.

Considering the below mongoConfig and commands for starting server and mongo client:-

mongoConfig.cfg

```
storage:
    dbPath: "../DB"
  security:
    clusterAuthMode: x509
  net:
    port: 27001
  ssl:
    mode: "requireSSL"
    PEMKeyFile: "../server/security/one.pem"
    clusterFile: "../server/security/one.pem"
    CAFile: "../server/security/rootCA.crt"
```

Commands in Prompt:-

```
cPrompt> mongod -v --config "../custom/mongoConf.cfg" --replSet "one"

cPrompt> mongo -ssl --sslPEMKeyFile "../client/security/oneHost.pem" --sslCAFile "../client/security/rootCA.crt" --host mylocalhost --port 27001
```

1) Is it a oneWay or a twoWay SSL/TLS ?

2) How authentication between members of replicaSet takes place (mongod - mongod while doing replication) and between server-client (mongod-mongo say mongoShell or application) ?

3) Which version of TLS is used ?

Can someone explain in detail ?

Answer (score 6):

This is an old question, however I was facing the same issues and it took me a lot of time to get it working. Some items are rather essential but quite hidden in the documentation.

I try to give an overview without doing simple copy/paste from the MongoDB documentation.

In general a x.509 certificate in MongoDB provides these functions:

- Generate keys to encrypt the connection
- Ensure the connection is established from correct host (i.e. the declared hostname matches the actual hostname)
- Authenticate a client (instead of using username + password or keyfile)

As starting point, one should have a look at these tutorials:

- [TLS/SSL Configuration for Clients](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl-clients/)
- [Configure `mongod` and `mongos` for TLS/SSL](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/)
- [Use x.509 Certificates to Authenticate Clients](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/configure-x509-client-authentication/)
- [Use x.509 Certificate for Membership Authentication](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/configure-x509-member-authentication/)

TLS/SSL settings are defined in this [configuration file section](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net-options):

```
net:
   tls:
      certificateKeyFile: server.pem
      CAFile: server-ca.crt
      clusterFile: member.pem
      clusterCAFile: cluster-ca.crt
```

They correspond to [command line options](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/program/mongos/#tls-options)

- `--tlsCertificateKeyFile server.pem`
- `--tlsCAFile server-ca.crt`
- `--tlsClusterFile member.pem`
- `--tlsClusterCAFile cluster-ca.crt`

All other TLS/SSL related parameters are well documented and usually they should not cause any confusion or misunderstanding.

### Step 1

When a client tries to establish a TLS/SSL enabled connection, then the `mongod/mongos` server presents a **server certificate**. The client verifies this certificate with a CA.

- A *client* can be a normal client (e.g. the Mongo shell `mongosh`) or an internal Replica Set / Sharded Cluster member
- The server certificate is always the same, `mongod/mongos` does not distinct the client types
- The server certificate is defined by parameter

  `net.tls.certificateKeyFile` or `--tlsCertificateKeyFile`
- A normal client can verify the server certificate for example with these:

  - Option `--tls --tlsCAFile server-ca.cer`
  - Option `--tls --tlsUseSystemCA`
  - Connection string parameter `tls=true&tlsCAFile=server-ca.cer`
  - `--tlsUseSystemCA` exists only as option, you cannot define it in connection string. Would be like this:

    `mongosh --tlsUseSystemCA "mongodb://localhost/?tls=true"`
- An internal Replica Set / Sharded Cluster member verifies the server certificate by parameter

  `net.tls.CAFile` or `--tlsCAFile`
- If `net.tls.CAFile` or `--tlsCAFile` is not specified and you are not using x.509 authentication, the system-wide CA certificate store will be used. If you use x.509 authentication, then `net.tls.CAFile` or `--tlsCAFile` is required.

### Step 2

The client presents a client certificate to the `mongod/mongos` server. The client certificate can be used to authenticate the user. In this case, you don't have to provide a password/keyfile.

- For normal client, x.509 authentication is enabled by user creation, e.g.
  `db.getSiblingDB("$external").runCommand({createUser: "CN=myName,OU=myOrgUnit,O=myOrg,..."})`
- For Replica Set / Sharded Cluster member, x.509 authentication is enabled by parameter
  `security.clusterAuthMode: x509`

A normal client (e.g. `mongosh`) provides **client certificate** for example by these parameters:

- `mongosh --tls --tlsCertificateKeyFile client.pem` (no x.509 authentication)
- `mongosh --tls --authenticationDatabase $external --authenticationMechanism MONGODB-X509 --tlsCertificateKeyFile client.pem` (with x.509 authentication)
- `mongosh "mongodb://username:secret@localhost/?tls=true&authSource=admin&tlsCertificateKeyFile=client.pem"` (no x.509 authentication)
- `mongosh "mongodb://localhost/?tls=true&authSource=$exernal&tlsCertificateKeyFile=client.pem&authMechanism=MONGODB-X509"` (with x.509 authentication)

An internal Replica Set / Sharded Cluster member provides **member certificate** by parameter `net.tls.clusterFile` or `--tlsClusterFile`

- The `monogd/mongos` sever verifies the client/member certificate with Root-CA defined by parameter `net.tls.clusterCAFile` or `--tlsClusterCAFile`
- The *client* can be a normal client (e.g. the Mongo shell `mongosh`) or an internal Replica Set / Sharded Cluster member
- The Root-CA is always the same, `mongos/mongod` does not distinct between client certificate and member certificate
- If `net.tls.clusterCAFile` or `--tlsClusterCAFile` is not defined, then `net.tls.CAFile/--tlsCAFile` is used for verification.

#### Pitfalls:

- Some MongoDB documentations just use the term "*certificate*" without a clear statement whether it applies to *client certificates* or *server certificates* or both. And often MongoDB documentation just use the term "*client certificate*" without a clear statement whether it applies to normal user client certificates or internal membership client certificates in a Replica Set / Sharded Cluster deployment.

  In this answer I use terms "server certificate", "client certificate" and "member certificate" for better understanding.
- Server certificates and Member certificates must have **the same** `O`, `OU`, and `DC` in their subject name.

  Starting in MongoDB version 7.0 you can change this behavior by setting `net.tls.clusterAuthX509.attributes`, however so far I did not test it.
- Client certificates and Member certificates must have **different** `O`, `OU`, and `DC` in their subject name
- Parameter pairs `certificateKeyFile/CAFile` and `clusterFile/clusterCAFile` are **not** used to separate connections from normal clients and connections from Replica Set / Sharded Cluster members. **They are used to separate client and server certificates, i.e. *incoming* and *outgoing* connections. In my opinion, these names are totally miss-leading.**
- You can use a common Root-CA, defined by `net.tls.CAFile`
- You can also use the same certificate for client, member and server. This common certificate can be even used for x.509 authentication of Replica Set / Sharded Cluster members. This certificate only provides encrypted connection and x.509 member authentication. Of course, you cannot use it for x.509 authentication of normal clients.
- Option `tlsAllowInvalidCertificates` has no effect on x509 authentication. For x509 authentication the certificate must be valid. Invalid certificates are only used to encrypt the connection.

#### Test cases:

```
openssl verify -CAfile server-ca.crt server.pem
openssl verify -CAfile cluster-ca.crt member.pem
openssl verify -CAfile cluster-ca.crt client.pem

# Verify server certificate:
openssl s_server -cert server.pem
# open another terminal
openssl s_client -CAfile server-ca.crt -quiet -no_ign_eof -status <<< Q

# Verify server and client certificate:
openssl s_server -cert server.pem -CAfile cluster-ca.crt -Verify 0
# open another terminal
openssl s_client -cert member.pem -CAfile server-ca.crt -quiet -no_ign_eof -status <<< Q
openssl s_client -cert client.pem -CAfile server-ca.crt -quiet -no_ign_eof -status <<< Q
```

#### Visualization

[image]

Or if you use only one CA certificate `common-ca.crt`:

[image]

Comment: thank you sir , helped a lot. been struggling with sharded cluster and x509 authenticadtion, the problem is that i create the user with its client certificate subject string in external databse, yet I'm unable to connect to mongos, it keeps saying UserNotFound.

Comment: @Hirbod Please open a new question for it