# `mongosh` cannot connect to MongoDB TLS cluster but `mongo` can -- MongoServerSelectionError: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames

Tags: mongodb, tls1.2, mongo-shell

### Metadata

Versions:

Ubuntu focal

MongoDB 5.0.14

mongod started with args:

```
/usr/bin/mongod --bind_ip_all --replSet=mongodb --auth --tlsCAFile=/etc/mongodb/external-ca.crt --tlsCertificateKeyFile=/etc/mongodb/external-cert.pem --tlsMode=preferTLS --clusterAuthMode=x509 --tlsAllowInvalidCertificates --tlsClusterCAFile=/etc/mongodb/internal-ca.crt --tlsClusterFile=/etc/mongodb/internal-cert.pem
```

### Problem

Problem: Cannot connect to replica set with TLS enabled via `mongosh`

I have TLS enabled on a replica set with two hosts. When I try:

```
sudo mongosh 'mongodb://<username>:<password>@<my ip>/admin?replicaSet=mongodb'  --tls --tlsCAFile /etc/mongodb/external-ca.crt --tlsCertificateKeyFile /etc/mongodb/external-cert.pem
```

I get:

```
MongoServerSelectionError: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: IP: <my ip> is not in the cert's list:
```

My logs show that this IP is in `"certificateNames"`:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-07T09:05:19.935Z"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23257,   "ctx":"ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor","msg":"The server certificate does not match the remote host name","attr":{"remoteHost":"juju-29df15-1","certificateNames":"SAN(s): mongodb-0, juju-29df15-1.lxd, mongodb-0.mongodb-endpoints, <my-ip>, CN:  <my-ip>"}}
```

### What else I tried

if I use `mongo` instead of `mongosh`:

```
sudo mongo 'mongodb://admin:5zymveLpT3rOlD6WACEuNM0wTJaNJTax@juju-29df15-1.lxd/admin?replicaSet=mongodb'  --tls --tlsCAFile /etc/mongodb/external-ca.crt --tlsCertificateKeyFile /etc/mongodb/external-cert.pem
```

this appears to connect after logging some messages, specifically:

```
connecting to: mongodb://10.23.62.38:27017/admin?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb&replicaSet=mongodb
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-07T09:21:01.646Z"},"s":"W",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23237,   "ctx":"ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor","msg":"You have an IP Address in the DNS Name field on your certificate. This formulation is deprecated."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-07T09:21:01.652Z"},"s":"W",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23237,   "ctx":"ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor","msg":"You have an IP Address in the DNS Name field on your certificate. This formulation is deprecated."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-07T09:21:01.654Z"},"s":"W",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23237,   "ctx":"ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor","msg":"You have an IP Address in the DNS Name field on your certificate. This formulation is deprecated."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-07T09:21:01.662Z"},"s":"W",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23237,   "ctx":"js","msg":"You have an IP Address in the DNS Name field on your certificate. This formulation is deprecated."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-12-07T09:21:01.664Z"},"s":"W",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23237,   "ctx":"ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor","msg":"You have an IP Address in the DNS Name field on your certificate. This formulation is deprecated."}
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("97e7e144-1bd7-4a94-b33d-958da2507bec") }
MongoDB server version: 5.0.14
================
Warning: the "mongo" shell has been superseded by "mongosh",
which delivers improved usability and compatibility.The "mongo" shell has been deprecated and will be removed in
an upcoming release.
For installation instructions, see
https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/install/
================
---
The server generated these startup warnings when booting:
        2022-12-06T16:56:40.822+00:00: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
        2022-12-06T16:56:42.686+00:00: While invalid X509 certificates may be used to connect to this server, they will not be considered permissible for authentication
---
---
        Enable MongoDB's free cloud-based monitoring service, which will then receive and display
        metrics about your deployment (disk utilization, CPU, operation statistics, etc).

        The monitoring data will be available on a MongoDB website with a unique URL accessible to you
        and anyone you share the URL with. MongoDB may use this information to make product
        improvements and to suggest MongoDB products and deployment options to you.

        To enable free monitoring, run the following command: db.enableFreeMonitoring()
        To permanently disable this reminder, run the following command: db.disableFreeMonitoring()
---
mongodb:PRIMARY>
```

And then I can execute commands in this shell (yay).

### Questions

So I have two questions:

1. why can I connect with `mongo` but not with `mongosh`
2. why am I getting the error `MongoServerSelectionError: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: IP: <my ip> is not in the cert's list:` if I can see `<my-ip>` in `"certificateNames"`?

Comment: I think the warnings and errors are quite clear. You can use [net.tls.allowInvalidHostnames](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-net.tls.allowInvalidHostnames) and/or option `--tlsAllowInvalidHostnames`

Comment: Why do you run `mongosh` as root?

Comment: `mongosh` is run as root since the TLS files require root permission @WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: Looks like security has been improved in new `mongosh` that's quite normal, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I have no answer for `1. why can I connect with mongo but not with mongosh`

But for `2.` this error occurs because when creating the Certificate Signing Request the IP address was provided via DNS subject alternative names. To resolve this I made my Certificate Signing Request with the IP address as the alternative name.

Comment: I think it should be the other way around. Instead of adding an IP address to subject alternative names you should use the hostname in connection string rather than the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question however, there is a miss-configuration in your setup.

### Problem

Your `mongod` is configured with

```
--tlsCAFile=/etc/mongodb/external-ca.crt
--tlsCertificateKeyFile=/etc/mongodb/external-cert.pem
--tlsClusterCAFile=/etc/mongodb/internal-ca.crt
--tlsClusterFile=/etc/mongodb/internal-cert.pem
```

So, these `openssl` checks should be OK:

```
cd /etc/mongodb
openssl verify -CAfile ./external-ca.crt ./external-cert.pem
openssl verify -CAfile ./internal-ca.crt ./internal-cert.pem
```

However, this connection with `mongosh` (or any other client) should fail:

```
cd /etc/mongodb
mongosh --tls --tlsCAFile ./external-ca.crt --tlsCertificateKeyFile ./external-cert.pem
```

It works only because you set `--tlsAllowInvalidCertificates` in your `mongod` configuration, you may find a warning message in `mongod` logfile. Without `--tlsAllowInvalidCertificates` option in `mongod` the connection attempt should fail.

### Explanation

Your `mongod` configuration corresponds to this `openssl` client/server:

```
cd /etc/mongodb
# simulate mongod server:
openssl s_server -CAfile ./internal-ca.crt -cert ./external-cert.pem

## open another terminal ##

cd /etc/mongodb
# -> simulate connection from other replica set member:
openssl s_client -CAfile ./external-ca.crt -cert ./internal-cert.pem -quiet -no_ign_eof -status <<< Q
# Should be OK

# -> simulate connection from mongosh:
openssl s_client -CAfile ./external-ca.crt -cert ./external-cert.pem -quiet -no_ign_eof -status <<< Q
# Should fail
```

Parameter pairs `tlsCAFile/tlsCertificateKeyFile` and `tlsClusterCAFile/tlsClusterFile` are **not** used to distinguish between "normal" client connections (e.g. from `mongosh`) and internal replica membership connections! They are used to separate between **incoming** and **outgoing** connections.

### Solution

Assuming you don't use dedicated client certificates, the `mongosh` connection should be

```
cd /etc/mongodb
mongosh --tls --tlsCAFile ./external-ca.crt --tlsCertificateKeyFile ./internal-cert.pem 'mongodb://<username>:<password>@<my ip>/admin?replicaSet=mongodb'
```

However, this is a security risk! The client can misuse the certificate and logon as internal replica set member. A malicious client can simply connect with

```
cd /etc/mongodb
mongosh --tls --tlsCAFile ./external-ca.crt --tlsCertificateKeyFile ./internal-cert.pem --authenticationMechanism X509 'mongodb://<my ip>/admin?replicaSet=$external'
```

in order to get full system privileges on the Mongo database.

Better use dedicated client certificate, it would need to be signed like this:

```
openssl x509 -in client-cert.csr -CA internal-ca.crt -CAkey internal-ca.key -out client-cert.crt  ...

mongosh --tls --tlsCAFile ./external-ca.crt --tlsCertificateKeyFile ./client-cert.pem
```

Note, the client certificate subject `O`, `OU`, `DC` must be different to the internal-cert `O`, `OU`, `DC`. Otherwise it is considered as a member certificate.

Find a few more details in [How Security in MongoDB works (using x.509 cert)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41302023/how-security-in-mongodb-works-using-x-509-cert/75043317#75043317)