# Configuring TLS for Percona mongodb sharding setup

Tags: mongodb, percona

I tried to setup TLS authentication for my sharded cluster. Created a secret with base64 encoded cert keys. The encoded certs are in format of ca.crt tls.crt and tls.key

````
data:
ca.crt: XXXXXX
tls.crt: XXXXXX
tls.key: XXXXXX
kind: Secret
name: my-testdb-psmdb-mongo
namespace: percona-operator
type: kubernetes.io/tls

And mentioned in cluster.yaml

secrets:
ssl: my-testdb-psmdb-mongo
sslInternal: my-testdb-psmdb-mongo```

Error:
in cfg-

`QUERY [js] uncaught exception: TypeError: db.isMaster(…).$configServerState is undefined 
(shell eval):1:1 [main] exiting with code -4 exit_status=0
Exit: connect to PBM: create mongo connection: create mongo client: tls: private key does not match public key`
````

Comment: 1. What should be certificate format included in secret?
2. Is there any extended cert configuration so that we can add our own cluster issuer like venafi

Comment: How does your mongod/mongos config file look like?

Comment: mongod --bind_ip_all --auth --dbpath=/data/db --port=27017 --replSet=rs0 --storageEngine=wiredTiger --relaxPermChecks --clusterAuthMode=x509 --shardsvr --enableEncryption --encryptionKeyFile=/etc/mongodb-encryption/encryption-key --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB=0.25 --wiredTigerIndexPrefixCompression=true --tlsMode preferTLS --tlsCertificateKeyFile /tmp/tls.pem --tlsAllowInvalidCertificates --tlsClusterFile /tmp/tls-internal.pem --tlsCAFile /etc/mongodb-ssl/ca.crt --tlsClusterCAFile /etc/mongodb-ssl-internal/ca.crt

Comment: Just a note, the certificate files `/tmp/tls.pem` and `/tmp/tls-internal.pem` should be a private and secure as possible, e.g. in the `mongod` $HOME directory with permissions `0400`. A .pem file contains the certificate and the private key - usually **everybody** can read/write the `/tmp` directory. Apart from that, on many systems, `/tmp` is cleaned on reboot by default, i.e. you loose your certificates. But maybe in this case it is just for testing.

Answer (score 0):

For such complex configuration I suggest to use a [configuration file](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/) instead of command line options. And I recommend that you do mix configuration file and command line options.

Converting your TLS options into configuration file would be this one:

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIpAll: true
  tls:
    mode: preferTLS
    certificateKeyFile: /tmp/tls.pem
    CAFile: /etc/mongodb-ssl/ca.crt
    clusterFile: /tmp/tls-internal.pem
    clusterCAFile: /etc/mongodb-ssl-internal/ca.crt
```

First verify the certificates:

```
openssl verify -CAfile /etc/mongodb-ssl/ca.crt /tmp/tls.pem
openssl verify -CAfile /etc/mongodb-ssl-internal/ca.crt /tmp/tls-internal.pem
```

Check if they work:

```
openssl s_server -cert /tmp/tls.pem -CAfile /etc/mongodb-ssl-internal/ca.crt
# open another terminal
openssl s_client -cert /tmp/tls-internal.pem -CAfile /etc/mongodb-ssl/ca.crt -quiet -no_ign_eof -status <<< Q
```

Then check the subject DN:

```
openssl x509 -noout -subject -nameopt RFC2253 -in /tmp/tls.pem
openssl x509 -noout -subject -nameopt RFC2253 -in /tmp/tls-internal.pem
```

The `O`, `OU`, and `DC` must be the same in both certificates.

Option `tlsAllowInvalidCertificates` has no effect on x509 member authentication. For x509 authentication the certificate must be valid. Invalid certificates are only used to encrypt the connection.

You may need to add

```
net.tls.allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates: true
```

depending on whether your clients use certificates or not.

Have also a look at [How Security in MongoDB works (using x.509 cert)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41302023/how-security-in-mongodb-works-using-x-509-cert/75043317#75043317)