# MongoDB error "SSL peer certificate revocation status checking failed: Could not verify X509 certificate store for OCSP Stapling"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ssl, tls1.3

I have a project that connects to a MongoDB (version 4.4.18) on a different server. The MongoDB server has a TLS certificate, the project server does not present one for this connection.

The connection string used is
`mongodb://user:password@mongo.server.com:27017/database3?tls=true`

This has been working for years, but since end of January MongoDB refuses the incoming connection with the error message
`SSL peer certificate revocation status checking failed: Could not verify X509 certificate store for OCSP Stapling`

This seems to make no sense since the project server does not even provide a certificate. I even tried adding `tlsInsecure` to the connection string without success.

Update:
Client is MongoDB NodeDriver, the error messages are on mongod on the database server.

Things I did without solving the problem:

- I checked the OCSP response for the cert of the database server manually, it was "good"
- I revoked the certificate and issued a new one
- I added the option `tlsAllowInvalidCertificates=true` to the connection string

Comment: @SteffenUllrich The statement seems to be correct. The MongoDB server provides a **server** certificate to the client. The client can use (i.e. verify) this server certificate by parameter `tls=true` or ignore it (unless server parameter `net.tls.mode` is set to `requireTLS`). This is independent from providing a **client** certificate.

Comment: How does the server configuration look like? Do you provide a CAFile?

Comment: The CAFile was old due to a misconfiguration in acme.sh ;( However fixing that did not solve the problem :(

Comment: Config: mode: requireTLS, certificateKeyFile: /home/xyz/mongo.pem, CAFile: /home/xyz/ca.pem, allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates: true. The file mongo.pem is a concatenation of fullchain.pem & key.pem.

Comment: Unless you have a ReplicaSet or Sharded Cluster, you don't need to specify any `CAFile` if your client does not provide a client certificate. The CAFile is not used at all. What do you mean by `fullchain.pem`? The `certificateKeyFile` file must contain only the server certificate (i.e **ONE** single certificate) and the according private key. However, on the client side you usually specify the CA with `tlsCAFile=ca.pem` or parameter `--tlsUseSystemCA` to use the system CA store. But I don't know how the Node.js driver works in detail, perhaps system CA store is the default.

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41302023/how-security-in-mongodb-works-using-x-509-cert/75043317#75043317 - despite it could be a bit an overkill for your case.

Comment: AllowInvalidCertificates must be set on the server, because the server complains about the certificate. The first version of your question was not clear in that point. However, I still don't understand why it is complaining at all, because the server should not receive any certificate which needs to be verified.

Comment: Thank you for the link, it was a good read but I still don`t understand why the problem exists. After many attempt it turns out I need the options 'ocspEnabled: false' and 'allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates: true'. 'AllowInvalidCertificates' does not seem to be necessary. I also removed the CA File from the config. Since this is a small private project I will leave it this way and be happy :)

Comment: The configuration is logical. Your client does not provide a certificate, so the server does not verify anything. Thus `allowInvalidCertificates` on the server has no effect. `allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates` must be false, because you set `mode: requireTLS` In your setup "requireTLS" means "require a TLS encrypted connection". The encryption keys are always provided by the server certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your server certificate has been revoked by your OCSP server. Check your server certificate, you may have to renew it. You can verify the certificate with openssl, see for example [OpenSSL: Manually verify a certificate against an OCSP](https://raymii.org/s/articles/OpenSSL_Manually_Verify_a_certificate_against_an_OCSP.html)

On `mongod/mongos`, you can disable OCSP with server parameter [ocspEnabled](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/parameters/#mongodb-parameter-param.ocspEnabled)

You did not tell us, which client you use, for `mongosh` the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/reference/options/) says:

> When using the system SSL certificate store, OCSP (Online Certificate Status Protocol) is used to validate the revocation status of certificates.

So, maybe it is valid also in your case. Looks like, when you explicitly define the CA file either with parameter `--tlsCAFile <filename>` or in connectionString

```
mongodb://user:password@mongo.server.com:27017/database3?tls=true&tlsCAFile=<filename>
```

then OCSP is not used. That's how I understand above statement.

Of course, you can connect with option `--tlsAllowInvalidCertificates` or

```
mongodb://user:password@mongo.server.com:27017/database3?tls=true&tlsAllowInvalidCertificates=true
```

But maybe that is not the most secure solution. Just a note, with an invalid server certificate the connection is still encrypted by TLS/SSL, only the identity of the server is not verified/guaranteed anymore.

**Update:**

Looks like you run into this issue: [Blocking networking calls can delay sync-source resolution indefinitely](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-54900), I had the same problem when I updated my MongoDB to version 6. Due to miss-configuration of our firewalls, the MongoDB server cannot reach the OCSP server. In earlier versions, the MongoDB server simply ignored the OCSP check. Now, in newer versions the communications stops, i.e. the connection cannot be established.

In principle I see three solutions:

- Ensure that the MongoDB server can connect to the OCSP server. The OCSP server is defined in the CA certificate.
- Use a CA without OCSP check (maybe not really a feasible solution)
- Disable OCSP by setting server parameter `ocspEnabled: false`

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I updated my question with the solutions attempted. Configuring mongod with ocspEnabled: false works and bypasses the problem. However I still have no clue why the problem exists in the first place.