# Enabling TLS on bitnami/mongodb

Tags: mongodb, ssl, kubectl

I'm using the bitnami mongodb image inside k3d and I'm trying to enable tls on the mongo image, following the details outlined here https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/mongodb. I've generated my own `issuing_ca.cert`, `ca_chain.cert`, `key.pem` and `certificate.cert`.

I've then configured the values file of the mongodb image like so:

```
tls:
  enabled: true
  existingSecret: mongodb-certs
  autoGenerated: false
```

And I created the mongodb-certs by running the following kubectl command:

```bash
kubectl create secret generic mongodb-certs --from-file=mongodb-ca-cert=./issuing_ca.cert --from-file=mongodb-ca-key=./key.pem
```

I've set up port forwarding to the mongo image, so I can connect to it on localhost:27017. And when I try connecting using the command:

```
mongo --tls --host localhost --tlsCAFile ./issuing_ca.cert --tlsCertificateKeyFile ./certkey.pem
```

(where certkey.pem is the key.pem followed by the certificate.cert in the same file).

I get the error: `SSLHandshakeFailed: SSL peer certificate validation failed: unable to verify the first certificate connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:372:17`

When I run: `echo Q | openssl s_client -connect localhost:27017 -showcerts` I'm getting back

```
...
Server certificate
subject=C = US, O = My Organisations, OU = IT, CN = mongodb-78f696dfc4-597fj

<cert details that I created>
...
```

I dont know where that first server certificate is coming from and I assume this is the issue. I'm not sure how to configure this mongodb image to just use my certificate details. I've tried using the other config options (tls.caCert and tls.caKey) but nothing seems to help.

Any help or pointers on how to configure this would be most helpful! Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you start the `mongod` service? Legacy shell `mongo` may have some difficulties/bugs with TLS, try new mongo shell `mongosh` Maybe have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41302023/how-security-in-mongodb-works-using-x-509-cert/75043317#75043317 - it could be an overkill because it handles the "full blown" configuration with client+server certificate and x.509 authentication by you should be able to extract the relevant parts for you.