# Different SSL key for mongodb replica set members

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-replica-set

I have 3 AWS EC2 instances. 2 for mongodb replica and 1 as my server.
I have followed [this article](https://rossbulat.medium.com/deploy-a-3-node-mongodb-3-6-replica-set-with-x-509-authentication-self-signed-certificates-d539fda94db4) to set up my replica set but there is no information on how to connect my nodejs server using mongoose.

I searched and got this as results

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://replica1.example.com:27017,replica2.example.com:27017,replica3.example.com:27017/mydatabase?ssl=true', {
  sslValidate: true,
  sslCA: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/ca.pem'),
  sslKey: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/client.pem'),
  sslCert: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/client.pem')
});
```

As per the article I have different sslKey and Cert for my replica member host 1 and replica member host 2

I am unable to connect to the database as it gives this as error

*Could not connect to database: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [replica2.example.com:27017] on first connect [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND replica2.example.com*

I believe this is because I did not specify the ssl key for 2nd member. But how can I do that?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41302023/how-security-in-mongodb-works-using-x-509-cert/75043317#75043317

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not specify the host names in the /etc/hosts path as I did in the replica members EC2 instances like this

```
35.xxx.111.yyy          host1.mongo.replset
yy.231.xxx.182          host2.mongo.replset
3.xxx.250.yy            host2.mongo.replset
```

Since the host name and respective IP was not defined in the server instance it was unable to find the address