# Getting SSL error, while connecting to MongoDB via Java SDK, but works with Mongo Compass

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

Trying to connect to ec2-hosted mongodb replicaSet from my local machine. I am able to connect successfully via MongoDB Compass, but getting SSLException error when doing via debzium-mongo-source-connector, which internally uses mongo java client.

Error:

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:684)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:555)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendCommandMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:381)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:329)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:101)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:45)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:131)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.startHandshake(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:73)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:182)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:193)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:157)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:127)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:349)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:292)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:287)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:144)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1418)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1324)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:440)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(SSLSocketImpl.java:829)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:1199)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.write(SocketStream.java:99)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:552)
    ... 10 more
    Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
            at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
            at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:110)
            at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:150)
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.encodeAlert(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:81)
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:380)
            ... 20 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:186)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:478)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:472)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:160)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:110)
    ... 17 more
```

I have checked the TLSVersion, suggested by some already present answer.

`openssl ciphers -v | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq`

Running on Server gave:
SSLv3
TLSv1
TLSv1.2
TLSv1.3

Running on Client(my local machine) gave:

SSLv3
TLSv1.2
TLSv1.3

Comment: `openssl ciphers` only prints a list of possible ciphers, it does not show what is used at your MongoDB. First you man use `openssl verify` to see if your certificates are valid. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41302023/how-security-in-mongodb-works-using-x-509-cert/75043317#75043317

Comment: Sorry for maybe a noob question, but Why does SCRAM auth don't work ? when tried with mongo atlas, I just used mongo connection-string containing username and password, there I didn't use any certificates.

Comment: Maybe that's the problem. Perhaps the MongoDB requires a SSL/TLS certificate.