# MongoDB OpsManager 4.0.8 - Error dialing for SSL connection. Server addr - Change SSL

Tags: mongodb, ssl, certificate

I have a small MongoDB Cluster with OpsManager Version 4.0.8.
I had to change the SSL Certificates on the nodes with newer ones because my internal CA has changed but I am getting errors like: `Error dialing for SSL connection` in the automation-agent.log
I did change the cert files with new ones locally on servers and also trough GUI in Authentication &TLS/SSL settings. Maybe I have missed something here or there is some other way to change the SSL Certs propery for this cluster. The certificates are externally signed and not self-signed.
Thanks in advance.

Config:

```
MongoDB Enterprise data0:SECONDARY> db.serverCmdLineOpts()
{
        "argv" : [
                "/var/lib/mongodb-mms-automation/mongodb-linux-x86_64-4.0.6-ent/bin/mongod",
                "-f",
                "/data/data0_1/automation-mongod.conf"
        ],
        "parsed" : {
                "config" : "/data/data0_1/automation-mongod.conf",
                "net" : {
                        "bindIp" : "localhost,111.222.333.555,222.333.448.442",
                        "port" : 27017,
                        "ssl" : {
                                "CAFile" : "/etc/security/manager/keyall.pem",
                                "PEMKeyFile" : "/var/lib/mongodb-mms-automation/xxxxzzzz_2023.pem",
                                "mode" : "allowSSL",
                                "weakCertificateValidation" : true
                        }
                },
                "processManagement" : {
                        "fork" : true
                },
                "replication" : {
                        "enableMajorityReadConcern" : true,
                        "replSetName" : "data0"
                },
                "security" : {
                        "authorization" : "enabled",
                        "keyFile" : "/var/lib/mongodb-mms-automation/keyfile"
                },
                "setParameter" : {
                        "authenticationMechanisms" : "SCRAM-SHA-1"
                },
                "storage" : {
                        "dbPath" : "/data/data0_1",
                        "engine" : "wiredTiger",
                        "journal" : {
                                "enabled" : true
                        }
                },
                "systemLog" : {
                        "destination" : "file",
                        "path" : "/data/data0_1/mongodb.log"
                }
        },
        "ok" : 1,
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1693370659, 1),
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1693370659, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"fdfdse/ffdsfsdfdgfgfhhhghgrI="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong("5454365645433245")
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you restart the services? How does your configuration file looks like?

Comment: Hi. I have restarted many times the services. The config was deployed trough gui. I am using MONGODB-CR/SCRAM-SHA-1 for OpsManager Agents. And also clientCertificate Mode is otpional. And I have the chainf of the certs as base64 encoded pasted into one file and defined inside CA File Path. Which configs are you interrested also ?

Comment: You can get it with `db.serverCmdLineOpts()`

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the post with the config output.

Comment: I guess you get this error when you try to connect. How do you connect?

Comment: Which error do you mean? I am getting those errors inside the automation-agent.log [cm/connectionpool/connectionpool.go:func1:666] <metricsCollector> [555] Error dialing for SSL connection. Server addr: server01:37023 ; Client Cert: <nil>. Identity = __system@local[[MONGODB-CR/SCRAM-SHA-1 SCRAM-SHA-256]][1024] : dial tcp: lookup server04 on 17.16.44.13:53: dial udp 13.42.34.34:53: i/o timeout

Comment: And it seems that opsmanager cannot connect do Data0 Cluster and I cannot browse data inside webgui

Comment: Did you check the logfile `/data/data0_1/mongodb.log`?

Comment: Yes. No Problems there. I see this: [conn33675] Successfully authenticated as principal __system on local and nothing else.

Comment: Check the certificate, for example with `openssl verify -CAfile /etc/security/manager/keyall.pem /var/lib/mongodb-mms-automation/xxxxzzzz_2023.pem`

Comment: Hi. I think the new certificates are ok. I got an OK here.

Comment: I would say, open a case at MongoDB

Comment: Will do. Can it be, that somewhere else more in the Mongo configs the new CA info is missing?

Comment: In some cases the ssl implementation of MongoDB is more picky than `openssl`. For example, by accident I used the same private key for server certificate and for CA certificate. It failed, despite `openssl` returned "Ok". Does server certificate file has only the certificate and the private key? Note, `CAFile` is not needed/used, because it looks like you don't use any client certificate. See [How Security in MongoDB works (using x.509 cert)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41302023/how-security-in-mongodb-works-using-x-509-cert/75043317#75043317) for details

Comment: Hi. The certificate file that corresponds to the server names has also the cert and private key and I get ACCEPT OK after this command. openssl s_server -cert /var/lib/mongodb-mms-automation/server01.pem Using default temp DH parameters ACCEPT  ... But when I verify the CAFile I also see many certificates from the chain inside and also a private key and I get an error there. Using default temp DH parameters
error setting private key
139870534334384:error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch:x509_cmp.c:343:   Maybe I do not need the pkey in CAfile

Comment: But in the old CA File I also had a private key that has worked ok with openssl test , I just tested i right now. The question is which private key it was, I guess in the new one I have the one I generated from the server, but with 4096 and the old one had 2048 length or was from somewehere else

Comment: A CA certificate file should never contain the private key.

Comment: Try it on a chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148319/error-dialing-for-ssl-connection-server-addr-change-ssl