# Running a MongoDB-Replica-Set inside docker with x509 authentication: Container Startup fails with tlsMode not enabled,

Tags: mongodb, docker, ssl, replicaset

I am trying to set up a docker cluster/ replica-set with clusterAuthentication set to TLS.
We use mongodb:7 (latest) docker container from the official docker-hub.

Currently we are stuck at startup (after a painful learning process of how to configure a openssl-selfsigned cert and csr)

Starting the first replica-set node throws immediately two errors:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2023-12-13T14:39:18.314Z"},"s":"D1", "c":"ASSERT",   "id":23074,   "ctx":"main","msg":"User assertion","attr":{"error":"BadValue: need to enable TLS via the sslMode/tlsMode flag when using TLS configuration parameters","file":"src/mongo/util/net/ssl_options_server.cpp","line":228}}

{"t":{"$date":"2023-12-13T14:39:18.314Z"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20574,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Error during global initialization","attr":{"error":{"code":2,"codeName":"BadValue","errmsg":"need to enable TLS via the sslMode/tlsMode flag when using TLS configuration parameters"}}}
```

Which are more or less the same.
I can't figure out, why this error is thrown.
The tls-section is set in the mongod.conf, also it doesn't matter which value I use. (requireTLS, allowTLS or preferTLS)

We use this configuration:

file mongod.conf (yaml)

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
systemLog:
  verbosity: 3
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
net:
  tls:
    clusterAuthX509:
      attributes: O=TestOrganisation, OU=TestDepartment, CN=MongoDbCluster
    mode: requireTLS
    allowInvalidCertificates: true
    certificateKeyFile: /etc/certs/server.pem
    CAFile: /etc/certs/server.crt
    clusterFile: /etc/certs/server.pem
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0,mongodb-cluster
  port: 27017
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo
replication:
  replSetName: rs0
security:
  authorization: enabled
  clusterAuthMode: x509
```

We successfully generated the certs with following commands:

```
openssl genrsa -out server.key 4096
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -sha256 -days 1825 -config ca_req.conf -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout serverROOTCA.key -out server.crt

openssl req -new -out server.csr -key server.key -config req_ext.conf -extensions v3_req

openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA server.crt -CAkey serverROOTKey.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -days 730 -sha256 -extfile req_ext.conf -extensions v3_req
```

We used this file for both, csr and actual cert as req_ext.conf, the req_conf for rootCA looks different.

```
[CA_default]
copy_extensions = copy
[req]
distinguished_name = client_ca
req_extensions = v3_req
prompt = no
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = mongodb-cluster
DNS.2 = replace_me_1
DNS.3 = replace_me_2
[client_ca]
C = SC
ST = SC
L = SampleCity
O = TestOrganisation
OU = TestDepartment
CN = MongoDbCluster
[v3_req]
subjectAltName = @alt_names
keyUsage = keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = clientAuth, serverAuth
```

Also the server.pem contains both, key and cert with the corresponding prefixex BEGIN/END key or certificate. The "replace_me" values are actual alternative dns-names of the other servers.
Each server has its own docker-network and exposes the mongodb-instance on the same port later on

For docker we rely on run-scripts and pass some env-values and files:

```
 docker run -d --restart always --name mongodb-cluster \
    --network traefik \
    -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=someuser \
    -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=somepassword \
    -v $PWD/data:/var/lib/mongodb \
    -v $PWD/log/mongod.log:/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log \
    -v $PWD/conf/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf \
    -v $PWD/certs/server.crt:/etc/certs/server.crt \
    -v $PWD/certs/server.pem:/etc/certs/server.pem \
    -p SOMEPORT:27017 \
    mongo:7 mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf
```

We followed this documentation for using a tls-protected x509 instance:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/

We also tried to specify --tls or --tlsMode requireTLS as a start-parameter for the docker-run command, but this also results in the same error.

What could be the problem that this configuration does not work?

Edit:
Additionaly the purposes for the root_ca when running the command:

```
openssl x509 -in server.crt -noout -text -purpose

Certificate purposes:
SSL client : Yes
SSL client CA : Yes (WARNING code=3)
SSL server : Yes
SSL server CA : Yes (WARNING code=3)
Netscape SSL server : Yes
Netscape SSL server CA : Yes (WARNING code=3)
S/MIME signing : Yes
S/MIME signing CA : Yes (WARNING code=3)
S/MIME encryption : Yes
S/MIME encryption CA : Yes (WARNING code=3)
CRL signing : Yes
CRL signing CA : Yes (WARNING code=3)
Any Purpose : Yes
Any Purpose CA : Yes
OCSP helper : Yes
OCSP helper CA : Yes (WARNING code=3)
Time Stamp signing : No
Time Stamp signing CA : Yes (WARNING code=3)
```

EDIT 2:
The command

```
openssl -in server.pem -noout -ext keyUsage,extendedKeyUsage,basicConstraints
```

results in this output:

```
X509v3 Key Usage: 
   Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment
X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
   TLS Web Client Authentication, TLS Web Server Authentication
```

for the root ca i get this output

```
openssl x509 -in server.crt -noout -ext keyUsage,extendedKeyUsage,basicConstraints
No extensions in certificate
```

Additional following ca_req.conf is used for the root-ca:

```
[req]
distinguished_name = RootCa
req_extensions = v3_req
prompt = no
[RootCa]
C = DE
ST = SC
L = SampleCity
O = TestOrganisation
OU = TestDepartment
CN = RootCa

[v3_req]
basicConstraints = CA:true, pathlen:0
keyUsage = keyCertSign
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
```

Comment: Why do you use `clusterAuthX509.attributes`? Is it required? It's a new feature in MongoDB 7.0 - try to run without. You don't need to specify `clusterFile` if `clusterFile` and `certificateKeyFile` are the same certificate. Maybe have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41302023/how-security-in-mongodb-works-using-x-509-cert/75043317#75043317

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.
The linked stackoverflow-post seems to be pretty helpful, i will check it out!
To answer your question:
i added the attributes because they are the first config-params for clusterAuth which appear when you scroll down a little when browsing the doc:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/#certificate-authorities

Comment: In [OpenSSL Server Certificates for Testing](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/appendix/security/appendixB-openssl-server/#a.-create-the-openssl-configuration-file) it still states: "*When creating **server certificates** for internal membership authentication, the following attributes, if specified, **must match exactly** across the **member certificates**: Organization (O), Organizational Unit (OU), the Domain Component (DC).*" For me, it is not 100% clear what parameter `clusterAuthX509.attributes` really does and if/how it contradicts above statement.

Comment: In [version 6.0](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/core/security-internal-authentication/#member-certificate-requirements) it says: "*Each cluster member certificate must have identical Os, OUs, and DCs in their net.tls.clusterFile and net.tls.certificateKeyFile certificates.*" which means the same but not as clear like "for internal membership authentication server certificates must match [...] member certificates"

Comment: Thanks for your insights!
I just tried leaving out the clusterFIle section and also deleted the clusterAuthX509.attributes. but the same error occurs.
Just out of curiosity I tried using "clusterFile" as the only parameter instead of "certificateKeyFile", but the error still occurs. (same error, not another message)
Basically the goal is x509 auth between members.

I want to mention that the configuration worked immediately when just using the keyfile method for member auth.

Comment: Setting `mode: requireTLS` contradicts `allowInvalidCertificates: true`. x.509 certificates used for authentication must be valid! Try `mode: preferTLS` which enables TLS for member connections but normal clients can connect without certificate.

Comment: In your docker config you have set `-v $PWD/certs/root.crt:/etc/certs/server.crt` however, the mongod.conf has `CAFile: /etc/certs/serverROOTCA.crt` - I think it must be `-v $PWD/certs/serverROOTCA.crt:/etc/certs/serverROOTCA.crt`

Comment: Thanks for your insights.
I "anonymized" the data to not expose actual names of the certs and made a typo. I am sorry that this now caused trouble. I double checked the naming of all certs inside and outside the scripts anyway. So thats a good point.
I tried to use "preferTLS" but the error is the same. I will try those both different configs again.
When checking the cert-chain from the certificates everything looks fine.
Only a warning is displayed viewing the cert in , e.g. windows because of they are self signed

Comment: I just tried using **preferTLS** and commented the line `allowInvalidCertificates`.
The error still occurs.
I will switch to earlier versions of the mongodb container itself. Maybe this will help or can give me a different error-message

Comment: A little update: Using mongo in version 6 as container-image also throws the same error.

I will try to ommit the data in the .conf file and pass it as command-line parameters when starting the mongo container.

@WernfriedDomscheit 
Maybe you have insights understanding the error thrown from this class:
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/util/net/ssl_options_server.cpp

Do you have by chance deeper knowledge?

Comment: Yes, I saw this. It is the reason for my last proposal. Parameter `allowInvalidCertificates` was `sslWeakCertificateValidation` in earlier version. Did you check the certificates (commands are shown in my linked answer). Did you verify it with `openssl x509 -in server.crt -noout -text -purpose`?

Comment: I think maybe we are getting somewhere.
yesterday I seem to have overlooked this two lines running this command:

`openssl s_server -cert server.pem -CAfile root_ca.crt -Verify 0`

`verify depth is 0, must return a certificate`

`verify error:num=26:unsupported certificate purpose`


I also ran the command you mentioned in your last comment. I will put the output in the question.

Comment: What is the output of `openssl x509 -in ...pem -noout -ext keyUsage,extendedKeyUsage,basicConstraints` and `openssl x509 -in ...crt -noout -ext keyUsage,extendedKeyUsage,basicConstraints`? Something seems to wrong with the certificates. I just tried the same setup as your. I only get a small warning in the logs "Client connecting with server's own TLS certificate" - which is expected if you use only one certificate.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort!
I updated the question with the output of your commands.
They don't throw errors, but it looks like the rootCA is misconfigured, event though a csr for a cluster-cert is created successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CA output should be similar to this:

```
X509v3 Key Usage: critical
    Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
    CA:TRUE
```

I created my certificates like this:

CA-Certificate config-file `ca.conf`:

```
[req]
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
prompt = no
[req_distinguished_name]
C = CH
O = Company
OU = OSS
CN = Root CA
[v3_ca]
keyUsage = critical, keyCertSign, cRLSign
basicConstraints = critical, CA:true
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
```

Certificate config-file `mongo.conf`:

```
[req]
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions = v3_req
prompt = no
[req_distinguished_name]
C = CH
O = Company
OU = OSS
CN = MongoDB
[v3_req]
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth, clientAuth
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = localhost
```

And then use these commands:

```
# Create private key for CA:
openssl genrsa -out ca.key 4096

# Create CA certificate:
openssl req -x509 -new -noenc -extensions v3_ca -config ca.conf -key ca.key -days 7305 -sha256 -out ca.cer


# Create certificate request with explicit private key:
openssl genrsa -out mongo.key 2048
openssl req -new -noenc -key mongo.key -config mongo.conf -out mongo.csr

# Alternative: Create certificate request with automatically generated private key
openssl req -new -noenc -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout mongo.key -config mongo.conf -out mongo.csr


# Create certificate, i.e. sign the certificate request
openssl x509 -req -in mongo.csr -CA ca.cer -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -days 365 -sha512 -copy_extensions copyall -out mongo.cer
```

Output:

```
openssl x509 -in ca.cer -noout -subject -issuer -ext keyUsage,extendedKeyUsage,basicConstraints -purpose

subject=C = CH, O = Company, OU = OSS, CN = Root CA
issuer=C = CH, O = Company, OU = OSS, CN = Root CA

X509v3 Key Usage: critical
    Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
    CA:TRUE

Certificate purposes:
SSL client : No
SSL client CA : Yes
SSL server : No
SSL server CA : Yes
Netscape SSL server : No
Netscape SSL server CA : Yes
S/MIME signing : No
S/MIME signing CA : Yes
S/MIME encryption : No
S/MIME encryption CA : Yes
CRL signing : Yes
CRL signing CA : Yes
Any Purpose : Yes
Any Purpose CA : Yes
OCSP helper : Yes
OCSP helper CA : Yes
Time Stamp signing : No
Time Stamp signing CA : Yes


openssl x509 -in mongo.cer -noout -purpose -subject -issuer -ext keyUsage,extendedKeyUsage,basicConstraints,subjectAltName -purpose

subject=C = CH, O = Company, OU = OSS, CN = MongoDB
issuer=C = CH, O = Company, OU = OSS, CN = Root CA

X509v3 Key Usage: critical
    Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
    TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
    DNS:localhost

Certificate purposes:
SSL client : Yes
SSL client CA : No
SSL server : Yes
SSL server CA : No
Netscape SSL server : Yes
Netscape SSL server CA : No
S/MIME signing : No
S/MIME signing CA : No
S/MIME encryption : No
S/MIME encryption CA : No
CRL signing : No
CRL signing CA : No
Any Purpose : Yes
Any Purpose CA : Yes
OCSP helper : Yes
OCSP helper CA : No
Time Stamp signing : No
Time Stamp signing CA : No
```

Once you managed to make it working, I would suggest to separate client and server certificate. That means

```
[v3_req]
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth, clientAuth
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = localhost
```

is split to

```
[v3_req]
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = localhost
```

and

```
[v3_req]
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = clientAuth
# On client certificates, subjectAltName (SAN) is not used
```

Using `openssl-ca` is a bit different. You can create certificates directly, i.e. without creating a certificate request, so a bit simpler to use. On the other hand `openssl-ca` uses a kind of mini-database for used/generated certificates, which makes it more complex again.

Just a note, some time ago I discovered [X Certificate and Key Management](https://github.com/chris2511/xca) (or https://hohnstaedt.de/xca/index.php/download) - much easier to use than `openssl` from command line.

Comment: While you were answering, I tried the -extensions-flag for the opensll req-command.
it kinda worked.

and got this output for command 

`openssl x509 -in root_ca.crt -noout -ext keyUsage,extendedKeyUsage,basicConstraints`
´X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
    CA:TRUE, pathlen:0
X509v3 Key Usage: 
    Certificate Sign
X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
   TLS Web Server Authentication`

Can you help me with the ca-tool ?
Our first attemps where just using openssl-req and there is no extfile parameter.
but we create the key and cert all in one line. What do need to run openssl-ca ?

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: Thanks for your update.
The first attempt (before splitting) didn't work  because of the openssl mismatch.
I had to change -noenc to -nodes and the copy command is not available on the command line, but in the .conf file.
So i did that.
Next step is starting a container and try it out.
After that i will split the certs as u mentioned
You were really helpful!, thanks a lot!

Comment: I am using openssl version 3.1.0. Older version may / may not support different options.

Comment: I now managed to get the same output as you above with openssl 1.1.1w 
However the container will not start (same error as before)
I then simply copied all your steps above and tried to startup a container on my local ubuntu maschine with the latest openssl version for it (3.02), all your commands worked perfectly fine without any changes
However, the mongodb-container will immediately stop and crash with the same error as before. (on my maschine and when i copy the crts on the server and map them into the container)

Comment: I kinda had a success.
I changed the start-script for the docker-contianer from 
`docker run -d mongo:7 mongod -f [file]`
to `docker run -d mongo:7 mongod --config [file]`

After this change I got a bunch of file-permission errors which i was able to solve.
Unfortunately its "almost" there.
The container starts up and initializes a db
last line in log is:
**MongoDB init process complete; ready for start up.**
I noticed this error in the startup-process:
`{"error":"NamespaceNotFound: config.system.sessions does not exist"}`
I don't know if tls would work now, bug i guess so.

Comment: I finally managed to get rid of all certificate errors.
Now I am able to start a container without and connect to the shell to execute the command rs.initiate(). 
Using **--config** instead of **-f** is crucial for my approach, since -f still throws the error with bad tlsMode option-flag.
However, I also had to remove multiple bind_ips from the config file to manage to startup the container properly. `bindIps: 0.0.0.0` does the trick
If you happen to come along the A5 from Basel to Karlsruhe grab a coffee at my office!
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think you must use `mongod --config=[file]` or `mongod -f [file]` but not `mongod --config [file]`. Having more than one IP in `bindIp` often causes problem, you can find several questions here on SO. Since MongoDB does not support multiple interface, it is useless anyway, You can also use `bindIpAll: true` which does the same.

Comment: Currently --config [file] without the "=" is working fine.
According to **bindIpAll** you are absolutely right.
Again, thanks alot for your help!