# Unable to connect to MongoDB server with authentication

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, x509certificate, mongo-shell

we are trying to install and configure MongoDB (version 7.0) on our Ubuntu server. We used [this](https://www.filecloud.com/supportdocs/fcdoc/latest/server/filecloud-administrator-guide/filecloud-site-setup/filecloud-high-availability/configure-mongodb-cluster-to-use-tls-ssl-with-cluster-authentication-and-mongodb-authentication-on-linux#undefined) document as our guide. This is what we did step by step (after having installed MongoDB server on the Ubuntu machine) from command line:

> 1 – Connect to one of the hosts and generate a new private key using
> openssl:

```
openssl genrsa -out mongoCA.key -aes256 8192
```

> 2 – Sign a new CA certificate:

```
openssl req -x509 -new -extensions v3_ca -key mongoCA.key -days 365 -out mongoCA.crt
```

> 3 – Issue self-signed certificates for all nodes

```
openssl req -new -nodes -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout mongossl1.key -out mongossl1.csr

openssl x509 -CA mongoCA.crt -CAkey mongoCA.key -CAcreateserial -req -days 365 -in mongossl1.csr -out mongossl1.crt

cat mongossl1.key mongossl1.crt > psmdb1.pem
```

This is our MongoDB configuration on our Ubuntu host machine:

```
net:   
  ssl:
    mode: requireSSL
    PEMKeyFile: /etc/mongodb/ssl/psmdb1.pem
    CAFile: /etc/mongodb/ssl/mongoCA.crt 
security:  
  authorization: enabled  
  clusterAuthMode: x509
```

Then we restart the MongoDB server on Ubuntu host.

Then we start mongo-shell (`mongosh`) on the Ubuntu host machine (the same one where MongoDB was just now configured and restarted), it is able to connect to that MongoDB instance fine.

However, when trying to connect from outside the mongo shell, either in the same Ubuntu host, or some other VM, through some client like PyMongo or even Compass, we are getting errors.

```
mongo --tls --tlsCAFile /etc/ssl/new/mongoCA.crt --tlsCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/new/psmdb1.pem --authenticationMechanism MONGODB-X509 --authenticationDatabase '$external' --host <our Ubuntu host public IP address> --port 27017
```

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: That image is really hard to see on small screens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed up several topics.

`security.clusterAuthMode: x509` is used for internal membership authentication in a Sharded Cluster and/or Replica Set. It looks like, you use a MongoDB Stand-alone instance, thus it does not apply.

In MongoDB you can use a **server** certificate to encrypt the connection. The server certificate is also used to guarantee that you connect to the correct server.

A client can authenticate with username/password or a **client** certificate.

In principle it is possible to use one single certificate for all, however it does not make much sense. Better create two certificates, one for the server and one for the client. You must also create the x.509 user. Have a look at [Use x.509 Certificates to Authenticate Clients](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/configure-x509-client-authentication/) and [How Security in MongoDB works (using x.509 cert)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41302023/how-security-in-mongodb-works-using-x-509-cert/75043317#75043317) to get a generic overview.

**Update**

Based on your comment, your config-file is almost correct.

As already mentioned `security.clusterAuthMode` is not relevant on a Stand-alone MongoDB, you can skip it. You should use `tls` options instead of deprecated `ssl` options:

```
net:
  tls:
    mode: requireTLS
    certificateKeyFile: /etc/mongodb/ssl/psmdb1.pem
    CAFile: /etc/mongodb/ssl/mongoCA.crt
security:  
  authorization: enabled
```

When you connect to MongoDB then you have to use these parameters

```
mongosh --tls --tlsCAFile /etc/ssl/new/mongoCA.crt --tlsCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/new/psmdb1.pem --authenticationDatabase 'admin' --user 'username' --password 'secret' --host <our Ubuntu host public IP address> --port 27017
```

Legacy mongo shell `mongo` has been removed in MongoDB version 6.0. Port 27017 is the default, thus you can skip it.

Options `--authenticationMechanism MONGODB-X509 --authenticationDatabase '$external'` are used when you like to authenticate the client with x.509 certificate - which you are not asking for.

Read/write privileges are defined granted roles in [createUser](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v7.0/reference/command/createUser/) command. IP ranges you can restrict with parameter `authenticationRestrictions`, for example

```
use admin
db.runCommand(
   {
     createUser: "api",
     pwd: "secret"
     roles: [
       { role: "dbOwner", db: "application" }
     ],
     authenticationRestrictions: [
        { clientSource: [ "10.20.30.0/24" ]
     ]
   }
)
```

As I already mentioned, I would suggest to create dedicated client and server certificate, see [extendedKeyUsage](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man5/x509v3_config.html#Extended-Key-Usage)

Comment: Thanks. We tried this command `mongosh --host <public_IP>:27017 –tls --tlsCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/mongo/psmdb1.pem`, getting error with message `MongoServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to <public_IP>:27017 closed`.

Comment: In order to provide decent help, I need to know what you like to achieve. So far it is not clear to me.

Comment: Hi, we want to install MongoDB server on Ubuntu machine (host), with a server side certificate, and ensure that only client with a client side certificate can access it for read and write, which means that the server MongoDB should be configured with both the server and client certificates. In addition, we want to restrict access to to the MongoDB from just a select set of clients (each of them will of course have the client side cert installed on it). Plus we want to secure the MongoDB server access via username and password, both of which will be present in config files on client machines.

Comment: Basically we want to ensure that our MongoDB server has three layers of protection - certificate (both server and client sides), limited range of IP addresses for client access (each of which will have the cert installed, and no client outside that list of IPs can access the MongoDB even if they manage to bypass the other two restrictions), and a username password combination. All three must work to get access for read/write to the MongoDB server.